# Constant velocity motion in a radiation bath

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermal-radiation, radiation-pressure

A perfect conducting plate is moving in an infinitely large space, which is in thermal equilibrium with the plate at absolute temperature $T$. Since the space is filled with black-body radiation, if there isn't any other force acting upon the plate, its motion will eventually stop due to the 'drag force' acted by radiation. (To be honest, I'm not able to explain why such a force is acted by the radiation.) As shown in the picture, a light beam is incident perpendicular to the plate so that it maintains constant velocity $v$. The problem is: "How much portion of the energy of the light beam is converted into the plate's kinetic energy?"

[image: Conductor plate in a radiation bath]

I tried to search for principles underlying the 'drag force' by the radiation but I couldn't convince myself because several conclusion in different papers seems to contradict each other. I guess the most reasonable explanation for this force is using the Doppler effect. Is this the right answer? If it is, how can I calculate this effect in this situation?

Comment: It looks like a trick question. Hint: the plate moves with constant velocity, and thus constant kinetic energy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really a drag force, it's radiation pressure, so it's kind of different.

It also matters if the plate is a blackbody..that's a harder problem, so make it perfect reflecting at all wavelengths.

An amazing thing about Planck's blackbody formula is that it transforms covariantly, even though it was created before relativity.,,but it has $\hbar$ and $c$ in it, which covers quantum mechanics and relativity.

What that means is that in the front (rear) direction, the plate sees a blackbody at

$$ T_{f, r}
 = \gamma^{\pm 1} T_0 $$

The energy density of that radiation is:

$$ E = \frac{4\sigma} c T^4$$

which gives a momentum flux:

$$ p = E/c = 2\frac{4\sigma} {c^2} T^4$$

where the 2 out front accounts for perfect reflection.

The difference is

$$ \delta p = 2\frac{4\sigma} {c^2} T^4 (\gamma-\frac 1 {\gamma})$$

$$ \delta p = 2\frac{4\sigma} {c^2} T^4 \beta^2$$

Your equation of motion is going to look like:

$$ \dot v = -av^2 $$

....which looks a lot like a drag force.

Comment: Btw: it plate is black body with poor thermal conduction, it will heat up and do its own differential radiating changing the drag, but the diff eq is more complicated with a time constant

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the plate has a rapidity $\beta = v/c$ where $v$ is measured in a frame of reference defined by the isotropy of the blackbody radiation field - this will mean there is a Doppler shift in radiation received that is a function of the direction it comes from.

What will happen is that each side of the plate will "see" a blackbody radiation field at a different temperature, because the temperature of a blackbody is shifted by exactly the Doppler shift introduced by the relative velocity of the plate. Exactly the same phenomenon is seen as the Solar System moves through the cosmic microwave background - the blackbody radiation field has a dipolar temperature distribution with the maximum temperature in the direction towards which the Solar System is moving.

Then, given that the radiation flux due to a blackbody is given by $\sigma T^4$, there is an imbalance between the radiation pressure/force experienced by one side of the plate compared to the other. The imbalance produces a drag force that opposes the velocity of the plate with respect to the blackbody radiation field and is proportional to $T_{\rm front}^4 - T_{\rm back}^4$. [Working out the constant of proportionality will I think involve some integration over the temperature distribution of each hemisphere]. This net radiation drag force will slow the relative velocity to zero, at which point the net force is also zero.

In your experimental set up, this net force, which will depend on $v$, will be exactly opposed by the force exerted on one side of the plate by the additional beam of radiation.